# wxpython app goes off screen on lower resolutions

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, resolution, maximize, sizer

Good evening/morning,

I have been working on a decently in depth program on my 1920x1080 monitor. I have set up everything to fit on my monitor when maximized. I have a few issues that that I think are related to the way I set up my sizers.

Firstly, when I decrease the actual size of the screen, the window contents do not decrease with it, but rather they are just cut off from the right side. So, a smaller screen means half the content, not half the content size.

This issue is also carrying over to when I adjust the resolution as well. With lower resolutions, I only get about half the content that actually fits on my screen. I don't know how I'm supposed to set up my sizers to fix this issue, so here's a brief description of the way I have them now:

```
import wx

class simpleapp_wx(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,(-1,-1))
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    """ Create All of the pieces for the GUI """
    def initialize(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        # Handles the creation of all of the buttons
        def make_button(text, starty, startx, height, width):
            button = wx.Button(self, -1, text)
            sizer.Add(button, (starty, startx), (height, width), wx.EXPAND)
            return button

        # Handles the c reation of all of the static text labels
        def make_label(text, starty, startx, height, width):
            self.label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, text, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize)
            sizer.Add(self.label, (starty, startx), (height, width), wx.EXPAND)
            return self.label

        # Create all of the labels for each slot and buttons
        for i in range(0, 4):
            # all the labels
            make_label('Voltage', 7, i*5, 1, 1)
            make_label('Current', 8, i*5, 1, 1)
            make_label('Power', 9, i*5, 1, 1)
            make_label('Rail 1', 6, (i*5)+1, 1, 1)
            make_label('Rail 2', 6, (i*5)+2, 1, 1)
            make_label('Rail 3', 6, (i*5)+3, 1, 1)
            make_label('Total Power', 6, (i*5)+4, 1, 1)
            make_label('Status:', 14, (i*5), 1, 1)
            # Global Rail commands for all 4 slots
            make_button("Margin Low", 1, (i*5)+2, 1, 1)
            make_button("Margin High", 1, (i*5)+3, 1, 1)
            make_button("Margin Off", 1, (i*5)+4, 1, 1)
            # Rail 1 for all 4 slots
            make_button("Margin High", 11, (i*5)+1, 1, 1)
            make_button("Margin Low", 12, (i*5)+1, 1, 1)
            make_button("Margin Off",  13, (i*5)+1, 1, 1)
            # Rail 2 for all 4 slots
            make_button("Margin High",  11, (i*5)+2, 1, 1)
            make_button("Margin Low", 12, (i*5)+2, 1, 1)
            make_button("Margin Off", 13, (i*5)+2, 1, 1)
            # Rail 3 for all 4 slots
            make_button("Margin High",  11, (i*5)+3, 1, 1)
            make_button("Margin Low",  12, (i*5)+3, 1, 1)
            make_button("Margin Off",  13, (i*5)+3, 1, 1)
            # Create the Configure buttons for each slot (only needs to run three times so needs if statement
            if i < 3:
                # Make the Configure buttons for Slot 1
                make_button("Configure",  10, i+1, 1 ,1)
                # Make the Configure buttons for Slot 2
                make_button("Configure",  10, i+6, 1, 1)
                # Make the Configure buttons for Slot 3
                make_button("Configure",  10, i+11, 1, 1)
                # Make the Configure buttons for Slot 4
                make_button("Configure",  10, i+16, 1, 1)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.SetSizeHints(-1,-1)
        self.Show(True)
        self.Maximize(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = simpleapp_wx(None,-1,'Add-in Card GUI')
    app.MainLoop()
```

I've been reading around, and I read somewhere about putting the gridbagsizer in a panel and that should work, so my modified header and closer were:

```
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    panel.SetSizer(sizer)
    panel.Fit()
    self.Fit()
    self.Show(True)
    self.Maximize(True)
```

This didn't change anything either. I've tried setting the SetSizeHints to specific resolutions, but that didn't work either.

So, what is causing this issue? I have a feeling it has something to do with me just using one sizer for all of the contents. If this is the case, what is the easiest way for me to fix this without having to completely reconstruct new sizers and break up the content?

Comment: Could you create a small runnable example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I posted a small working example. Sorry about the indentation though, I couldn't for the life of me get it to be right. It physically looks right on stack, but for some reason when I'm copying it to gedit, it messes up, so just watch out for that. The example is in the first text box above and replaced my old one.

Comment: I am not sure how you want it to behave in a smaller space, but you can use a `scrolledpanel`. `panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self) panel.SetupScrolling()`

Comment: I agree with @SelçukCihan. I would just use a `ScrolledPanel` for this. There are so many widgets, I'm not sure it could resize them in a way that they would be usable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the columns and rows of the sizer as growable:

```
...
for i in range(0, 20):
    sizer.AddGrowableCol(i, 1)
for i in range(0, 15):
    sizer.AddGrowableRow(i, 1)

self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
...
```

works on your example. Now, it still won't shrink down very far, because you've got a lot of widgets, and they've all got minimum sizes, but it will pack in at least a bit tighter. (And expand to occupy more space, if available.)

For at least wxPython>=3, you need to make sure that you only try to make a row or column growable if it exists.